# I am getting this message each time I open my terminal. And runs infinite times

Tags: bash

-bash: export: `Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin`:

> not a valid identifier

```
This is how my bash profile looks like
```

## Enable tab completion

```
            source ~/git-completion.bash

            # colors!
            green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
            blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
            purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
            reset="\[\033[0m\]"

            # Change command prompt
            export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
            # '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
            # '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
            # '\W' adds the name of the current directory
            export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

            alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
            # Homebrew
            export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
            # Homebrew
            export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin
            source ~/.bash_profile
            VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2
            source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
            source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I am getting this error every time i open my terminal

Comment: -bash: export: `Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: Could you please try putting your variable `PATH` value in `"` eg--> `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app"` and let me know if this helps. Since your directory name has spaces on it so try it out once and let me know then.

Comment: ...and which line exactly causes this?

Comment: after adding the quotes i get the following in the terminal "Last login: Mon Mar 19 13:49:43 on ttys000" ...but the loop runs in background

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt -  how am I to know which line causes error

Comment: There are site guidelines that explain how to create an MCVE, check those, they explain the process.

Comment: How is your file called? IF it is `.bash_profile` then you basically have infinity recursion

Comment: @Ferrybig     Yes it's .bash_profile

Comment: @Bryan Remove the last line from the file, you are sourcing itself, and that causes the recursion. With bash, you can source a file multiple times.

Comment: Still getting the same loop

Comment: I got this error while installing opencv for python

Answer (score 0):

```
    source ~/git-completion.bash
    # colors!
    green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
    blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
    purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
    reset="\[\033[0m\]"

    # Change command prompt
    export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
    # '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
    # '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
    # '\W' adds the name of the current directory
    export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"

    alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
    # Homebrew
    export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin"
    # Homebrew
    export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin"
    source ~/.git-prompt.sh
```

Comment: I removed the last 4 lines and changed the source and now it's working

Comment: But u have to install the opencv Again